# STM32F469-discovery CAN BUS configuration

Tags: stm32, can-bus, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, stm32cubeide

I initialized the CAN2 via STM32CubeIDE (from .ioc file) but the stm32f4xx_hal_can.c file is not imported in the Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver folder.
So I have no way of running HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan2) even though it is code generated via IDE/MX.
How do I get the correct stm32f4xx_hal_can.c file? Do I have to configure the CAN differently via the .ioc file?

Comment: did you try use older firmware versions, i learn that STM32Cube always have a bug in newer versions so i use older versions,
now i use STM32CubeMX v6.1.0 and STM32F4 firmware v1.25.2

Comment: I'm using the latest version of CubeIDE, thanks for the hint and i'll try it, after the trial i'll update this topic.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION** : i used an old versione of CubeMX (v6.3.0) to configure the CAN, then i generated the code and edited it with CubeIDE.
Thanks to [@Ali Mirghasemi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13839442/ali-mirghasemi) fot the hint.